# How to get extras from pip install in custom cmdclass command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

If I have a `setup.py` that looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install


class CustomInstallCommand(install):
  def run(self):
    install.run(self)
    # no information on used `extras` in `pip install`    


setup(
  name='myapp',
  version='1.0.0',
  install_requires=[
    'unidecode >= 1.0.0, < 2.0.0',
    'pyyaml >= 4.0, <= 5.1'
  ],
  extras_require={
    'url': ['requests >= 2.18, < 3.0']
  },
  cmdclass={
    'install': CustomInstallCommand
  }
)
```

Is it possible to get extras used in command `pip install` in setuptools command overrides in `setup.py` through `cmdclass` params?

In other words, if user runs command:

- `$ pip install -e .` - Through `cmdclass` override in `setup.py` get information that **none of the extras have been used in pip install**
- `$ pip install -e .[url]` - Through `cmdclass` override in `setup.py` get information that **extra `url` has been used in pip install** in order to do extra work in post-install script

I tried to override following commands through `cmdclass` but none of the classes gave me any information on what extras have been used in installation:

- `setuptools.command.install`
- `setuptools.command.build`
- `setuptools.command.egg_info`

I couldn't find any relevant documentation how to do it on `setuptools` and `distutils`.

Comment: Just curious, what exactly are you trying to do with the additional information?  Also, if you are packaging your package as a wheel, the extra install command wouldn't actually be executed.

Comment: Some of the extras that I have in setup.py require additional resource files to be downloaded. Currently those resource files are part of `git lfs` process. 

In more details, I have several extras in the project where each extra has multiple resource files it works with. I wanted to skip the situations where all resource files are pulled even if you were to use only one extra of the project. Maybe I am going into totally wrong direction with this setup.py for the use case I just described?

Comment: Yeah, you definitely don't want to approach it this way.  You should have your users execute some additional commands to get the resource files if they are to be downloaded, or package them directly with the package.  Not to mention `pip` actually does not call `setup.py` with the arguments (which includes the extras specified), but only to call it to "compile" the metadata for the package and read from it directly (have `setup.py` import `sys` and then `raise Exception(sys.argv)`, you will know what I mean), so it is actually _impossible_ to do what you wanted.

Comment: @metatoaster "*pip actually does not call setup.py*" That's not exactly true. `pip` certainly calls `setup.py` when installing from source dist or a VCS. `pip` does not call `setup.py` (even to read metadata ) at all when installing from a wheel because wheels contain the metadata. So what the OP wants could be implemented for source dist or a VCS installation.

Comment: @phd Please note the whole statement "pip actually does not call setup.py with the arguments", I am referring to pip not passing the `.[url]` to `setup.py`.

Comment: @metatoaster I agree.

Comment: @Toni I don't believe you can get the information as `pip` doesn't pass it to `setuptools`. It collects the list of requirements and installs it itself one by one.

Comment: @phd Also, OP wouldn't actually be able to use `pip` to install from source dist because of how `pip` uses `setup.py`, which was literally my whole point. If end users install the package without `-e` it would result in `pip` creating a wheel from the package, then installing the wheel, which would also not trigger the extra install command class.

Comment: Thanks @phd and @metatoaster! In the end what I wanted is to make it easier for end user when installing extras to have just one command to handle. With that in mind I would then either need to wrap pip install with some Makefile or bash in order to cover both package installation and resource download.