# how to see with python setuptools what extras have been selected

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I have a python package that includes a native c++ extension. The native extension has a few options for compilation that can be turned on/off with a macro. One of those is including cairo support. So that also has the python dependency on pycairo. But this should be optional. So I specified an `extras_require` argument for `cairo` that lists `pycairo` as dependency. Now how do I see what extras have actually been specified by the user at run time during build/installation, so I can also modify the extra_compile_args accordingly to add `-DWITH_PYCAIRO`. Unfortunately the [api docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.setup) don't even list the `extras_require` argument to `setup()`.

This is an abbreviated version of what I have so far.

```py
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    packages="mypackage",
    extras_require={
        "cairo": ["pycairo"]
    },
    ext_modules=[Extension(
        "mypackage._mypackage",
        [ "src/my_package.cpp"],
        language="c++",
        extra_compile_args=["-DOPTION1"]
    )],
)
```

One way I can see of implementing this is to use an additional environment variable like this:

```py
extra_compile_args=["-DOPTION1"]
if os.environ.get('WITH_CAIRO', False):
   extra_compile_args.append("-DWITH_PYCAIRO")

setup(
   .....
   ext_modules=[Extension(
        "mypackage._mypackage",
        [ "src/my_package.cpp"],
        language="c++",
        extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args
    )],
)
```

and then install with `WITH_CAIRO pip install .[pycairo]` but that seems kind of superfluous to specify the same option twice.

Comment: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=extras_require#optional-dependencies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083971/setup-py-how-to-find-user-specified-bracketed-extras#comment116861723_66083971 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737009/how-to-get-extras-from-pip-install-in-custom-cmdclass-command#comment98152860_55737009 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+extras_require

Comment: @phd interesting that the extras_requires arg is documented there but not in the function signature of the api reference. But in any case, what I am trying to do is modify the extra_compile_args based on the selected extras. I guess with the links, you're saying it's not possible? I have added a possible solution, but one that isn't ideal. Is there no way to find the extras before `setup()` is called? No environment variable or some other variable from pip?

Comment: Nope, I don't believe there is any way, sorry.